# ExtJS Paging Problem with ArrayStore

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am trying out a few things in ExtJS including displaying a grid with different functionalities.

In my page, I first declare a Javascript Array of about a hundred data which I store in a variable called `myArray`

Then, I do the following:

```
Ext.define('Fund2',{
extend:'Ext.data.Model',
fields:[{name:'Id'},
{name:'Id2'},
{name:'Name'},
{name:'Name2'},
{name:'Name3'},
{name:'Name4'},
{name:'Param1'},
{name:'Param2'},
{name:'Param3'}]
});

var myStore2=Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore',{
model:'Fund2',
data:myArray,
pageSize:10
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel',{
renderTo:'div2',
store:myStore2,
height:500,
width:500,
columns:[{text:'Id',dataIndex:'Id'},
{text:'Name',dataIndex:'Name'},
{text:'Additional',dataIndex:'Param1'}],
dockedItems:[{
xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
store:myStore2,
dock: 'bottom',
displayInfo: true
}]
});
```

On th page, the grid panel is displayed properly and filled with the data.

The paging toolbar is also available and computes the right amount of pages.

However, the data is not "paged"; all the records are shown in the grid.

Do you know where I made a mistake?

Comment: How you are paging the data?You mentioned that without paging all records are showing?

Comment: According to Sencha's documentation, you do not need to do anything more than attaching the paging toolbar to the store and setting the pageSize of the Store. (http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/guide/grid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this:

```
myStore2.on('load', function(store, records, successful, operation) {
            this.loadData(myArray.slice((this.currentPage-1)*PAGE_SIZE, (this.currentPage)*PAGE_SIZE));
        },myStore2);
```

Full version:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    var myArray=[];
    for (var i=0; i<100; i++) {
        myArray[i] = ['Id_'+i,'Id2_'+i,'Name_'+i,'Name2_'+i,'Name3_'+i,'Name4_'+i,'Param1_'+i,'Param2_'+i,'Param3_'+i];
    }
    var PAGE_SIZE = 10;

    Ext.define('Fund2',{
        extend:'Ext.data.Model',
        fields:[{name:'Id'},{name:'Id2'},{name:'Name'},{name:'Name2'},{name:'Name3'},{name:'Name4'},{name:'Param1'},{name:'Param2'},{name:'Param3'}]});

    var myStore2=Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore',{
        model:'Fund2',
        data:myArray,
        pageSize:PAGE_SIZE
    });

    myStore2.on('load', function(store, records, successful, operation) {
        this.loadData(myArray.slice((this.currentPage-1)*PAGE_SIZE, (this.currentPage)*PAGE_SIZE));
    },myStore2);

    myStore2.load();

    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel',{
        renderTo:Ext.getBody(),
        store:myStore2,
        height:500,
        width:500,
        columns:[{text:'Id',dataIndex:'Id'},
                 {text:'Name',dataIndex:'Name'},
                 {text:'Additional',dataIndex:'Param1'}],
        dockedItems:[{
            xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
            store:myStore2,dock: 'bottom',
            displayInfo: true
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved a similar problem using the
[Ext.ux.data.PagingMemoryProxy](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.ux.data.PagingMemoryProxy)

which works pretty well
consider that it's not in the standart build of ExtJS 4, you have to manually include it